# windows explorer restart whenever I try to navigate to a certain folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm using windows 7 32-bit. I don't know why windows explorer restarts everytime I try to navigate to the folder where I download videos.
What might be the cause of this?
I tried scanning the whole partition with avast free(updated) but it cannot find any threats.
I tried navigating other folders with the same depth but it doesn't restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A corrupt file can have this affect sometimes. Or a damaged sector on the harddisk.

Is explorer trying to create a preview of the file, or thumbnail? if so, turn this off.

Run the windows chkdsk on that drive.